# How to make script wait for sometime so the data from ajax response is being loaded and then capture the webpage

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am capturing the webpage but i want that the script should wait for sometime before capturing it because i am populating somedata using AJAX right now the script is not waiting and capturing the webpage before the ajax data is getting loaded.

i am using following code.

```
import blockspring
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json

def screenshot(request, response):
  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
  driver.set_window_size(request.params["width"] or 1024, request.params["height"] or 768) # optional
  driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
  driver.get(request.params["url"])
  driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
  response.addFileOutput("screenshot", "my_screenshot.png")
  response.end()


blockspring.define(screenshot)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reliable way to wait until the page is completely loaded, is using [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits). When there are AJAX requests they change something in the page. So you need to wait for those changes to occur. You have to determine what element is added (or removed) to the page as the last element, determine what the selector for this element is and wait for it.

This is the example from the documentation (it works the same way with PhantomJS):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

This code waits up 10 seconds until an error is raised. You can use this time to specify the acceptable time that the site loads or does some things. If it doesn't do them in time and the test case fails, you know either that the site is too slow and must be optimized or that the site has changed and you have to adjust. It can also be a network error and a million other things.

The static way of using `sleep` is easier to add, but may lead to unexpected results. When the AJAX request took longer than expected, the processing may continue before the page is loaded. If you use a long sleep time, then you give time away with unnecessary waits.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the screen  only after your Ajax Data is Loaded..You can set Manual Wait time as per your requirement. Say you want your script to wait for 5 sec. so just include this command in your script where you want it to be paused.

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait wait_for_Data = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait_for_Data.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.--("Our Ajax Data Loading Condition")));
```

Lets say in the worst case the our Ajax data takes 20 seconds to Load.Even though we have 20 sec assigned for our Web-element the execution will go to next step as soon as Ajax Data is Loaded completely avoiding unnecessary wait.

Comment: What happens when the Ajax takes 5.1 seconds?

Comment: @RobbieWareham : No Doubt it will capture the screen with-out loading the our Ajax data and will result into failure. The other best option i have updated in my answer above. Please let me know if we have more preferred option other then this. Thanks

Comment: Using WebDriverWait is far better than an explicit Thread.sleep